# Using が or は with 好き

Tags: particle-は, particle-が

> 値段が高いレストランはあまり好きじゃない

This is a sentence from my texbook and I can't understand why there is は after 
レストラン?
As I know, we always use が after something that we 好き.
In this sentence we doesn't like restaurants so shouldn't it be like this?

> 値段が高いレストランがあまり好きじゃない